# client PersistenceCapable NoClassDefFoundError while serializing Entity object from server to client using gwt

Tags: gwt, jpa, openjpa

I'm using apache open JPA to access my db at the server side. I'm trying to call from my gwt client to the server in order to retrive an entity object, but this requests always fails with the error message:NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/openjpa/enhance/PersistenceCapable.

I tried defining my enhanced entity classes at the gwt.xml file and it did not helped:

```
<set-configuration-property name="rpc.enhancedClasses" value="com.jobsin.domain.SystemUser,com.jobsin.domain.Keyword,com.jobsin.domain.Job">/
```

My server function:

```
public  SystemUser getCurrentUser() 
throws InvalidUser{

    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
    HttpSession session =  httpServletRequest.getSession();
    SystemUser user=null;

    Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
    SocialNetworkCookie cookie = network.generateCookieObject();
    if(!cookie.init(cookies)){
        session.invalidate();
        throw new InvalidUser(); // no user was connected, user need to login
    }

    //try get user details from db
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    SystemUserDAOImpl userdao = new  SystemUserDAOImpl(em);
    user = userdao.findUserByNetworkId(cookie.getMemberId());
         //make user detach
    em.close();

    return user;
}
```

SystemUser Class :

```
@Entity
public class SystemUser implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1673271845552139219L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id; 

    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String email;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
    private Date lastSearch;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Job> jobs = new HashSet<Job>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Keyword> keywords = new HashSet<Keyword>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to add the OpenJPA binaries to the GWT client classpath.

Comment: the openjpa jar is located under WEB-INF/lib library. I'm running the server (jeti)  using the gwt eclipse plugin. Anything else i should do?